# How to implement RTL for angular2 application using ng2-bootstrap?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng2-bootstrap

I have searched a lot to find a solution for RTL support for angular2 apps. But I could not find any yet. In fact, there is no official documentation to do this for angular 2 or ng2-bootstrap.

Can anyone help me to integrate RTL support in angular2 apps? I am using angular-cli for creating and building the project and ng2-bootstrap for UI elements.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you mean by arabic support ?

Comment: html page can display utf 8 so RTL on template is pretty sure

Comment: RTL or LTR is related to your CSS not angular app. ng2-bootstrap is using bootstrap framework. bootstrap doesn't support rtl. You can use third party style for making bootstrap rtl like:  https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl

Comment: Have you tried angular-cli? What I want to do is to create sass file for RTL css during angular-cli build process. Adding bootstrap-rtl does not convert my custom scss files to include RTL support